# How to iterate, search and display a specific element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I'm having a problem with a specific part of a program. What I want to do is iterate, search and display an element from an ArrayList.

So I tried implementing my own snippet to the main function of the code to try:

```
else if (menuChoice==3) {
           System.out.println("Search Student:");
           String search = input.nextLine();

           for (Student student : students)
           {
               if (students.equals(search)){
                   System.out.println(student);
               }
           }
       }
```

Hoping that it would iterate through the ArrayList and access/display that specific element in the list. It returns blank, what am I doing wrong?

Here's the whole code if you're wondering:

```
package student;
import java.util.*;

public class Student
{
private String r_name;
private int r_age;
private String r_course;
private String r_year;
private String r_section;
private String r_studno;

public Student( String name, int age, String course, String year, String section, String studno )
{
    r_name = name;
    r_age = age;
    r_course = course;
    r_year = year;
    r_section = section;
    r_studno = studno;
}

public String getName()
{
    return r_name;
}

public int getAge()
{
    return r_age;
}

public String getCourse()
{
    return r_course;
}

public String getYear()
{
    return r_year;
}

public String getSection()
{
    return r_section;
}

public String getStudno()
{
    return r_studno;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + r_name + ", Age: " + r_age + 
           ", Course: " + r_course + ", Year: " + r_year +
           ", Section: " + r_section + ", Student Number: " + r_studno;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   int menuChoice = 4;
   do {
       System.out.println("\t\t\tStudent Record Menu");
       System.out.println("\t\t1. Add Student\t2. View Students\t3. Search Student\t4. Exit");
       try {
           System.out.println("Enter a choice: ");
           menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           continue;
       }

       if (menuChoice==1)
       {
           System.out.println("Add a Student");
           System.out.println("Full name:");
           String name = input.nextLine();

           int age = -1;
           do {
               try {
                   System.out.println("Age:");
                   age = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                   System.out.println("Enter a number!");
                   continue;
               }
           } while (age <= 0);

           System.out.println("Course:");
           String course = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("Year:");
           String year = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("Section:");
           String section = input.nextLine();

           System.out.println("Student Number:");
           String studno = input.next();

           Student student = new Student(name, age, course, year, section, studno);
           students.add(student);

       } else if (menuChoice==2) {
           System.out.println("Students:");
           for (Student student : students)
           {
               System.out.println(student);
           }
       } else if (menuChoice==3) {
           System.out.println("Search Student:");
           String search = input.nextLine();

           for (Student student : students)
           {
               if (students.equals(search)){
                   System.out.println(student);
               }
           }
       }

   } while (menuChoice<4);
}
}
```

Comment: What creterea you try to use. You need to find student by name, course, section or something else?

Comment: I wanted it to display the whole content of that specific element (including name, age, course, year etc.) I didn't specify it clearly on the post above, sorry.

Comment: But for which student? For all or for specific student with specific name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the `ArrayList` `students` is equal to the `String` `search`. The result can only be false. I guess, you are trying to do the following:

```
for (Student student : students)
{
    if (student.getName().equals(search))
    {
        System.out.println(student);
        break;//assuming student name are unique. remove if not
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted it to display the whole content of that specific element (including name, age, course, year etc.) I didn't specify it clearly on the post above, sorry.

Comment: I see that you override the `toString()` method of `Student`, so doing a `System.out.println(student)` should output everything you specified. No ?

Comment: The `toString()` method was for printing all of the stored data in the ArrayList. So I guess, more or less, yes.

What I'm trying to do now is formulate a "Search" in the program, i.e. the program will prompt the user to input that student's ID number (Provided that it's already stored on the arraylist) and will display that specific student's information (name, age, course, section etc.)

Comment: I am not sure to follow: I dont see any ID in your code. If you want to print specific information about a student, replace ` System.out.println(student);` by ` System.out.println(student.getCourse());` for example.

Comment: The ID number is declared as `studno` in the code (short for Student Number). 

which is provided by the user when Adding a Student in the program.

So to clear my idea: I will compare the Student ID to an element on the ArrayList and when it finds a match, it will display ONLY that specific student's detail.

Comment: Ok, then a simple `if(student.getStudno().equals(search))` should do the trick.

Comment: Still no display. Should I add something to the `getStudno` method?

Comment: You should use the debugger and check if `if(student.getStudno().equals(search))` is actually true at some point.

Comment: I have little experience in using IDEs and debugging. How would I debug a program? 

Should I be putting a break point at `if(student.getStudno().equals(search))`?

Comment: Yes, and run the program in Debug mode. You really should go through the tutorials of the IDE as well. That will serve you for future projects

Answer (score 1):

You must compare the search key with the key id of student for example if all names are unique then use

```
 for (Student student : students)
       {
           if (student.getname().equals(search)){
               System.out.println(student);
           }
       }
```

You are compairing the whole student object reference with the search key how it will compare it

if you want to display the whole content then you will have to make a method in which you will get all details using the id eg:

```
getStudentbyname( String studentname){

here comes the code to get all data

}
```

then in your for loop call the method and store in array

```
 for (Student student : students)
       {
           if (student.getname().equals(search)){
              Arraylist<String> studentarr = student.getStudentbyname(student.getname());

System.out.println(""+studentarr)
           }
       }
```

Comment: Should be 'student.getName()'

Comment: So I will create a method that will get a specific student's details from the ArrayList, am I correct?

Sooo... I have theorized that, I will also access the contents of ArrayList on that method?